# C++ updating/changing variables from different class/variables

Tags: c++, class, variables

I'm a noobie at C++ and I was making a game for practice on Visual Studios and I just couldn't figure out how to update stats when exp was added. I tried changing the player level by adding exp but when I add 55 exp the player remained at level 1 still.

Main:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include "Game.h"

using namespace std;

void FalseLoad();

int main() {
    //Cool load intro
    FalseLoad();
    cout << "\n \n";

    Game::Game();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void FalseLoad() {
    int i = 0;
    int start;

    cout << "***Freelancer*** \n \n";

    system("PAUSE");

    while (i <= 100){
        cout << "Loading game... " << i << "% \n";
        i++;
        Sleep(110 - i);
        if (i == 100) {
                start = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Game.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace std;

Game::Game() {
    Player Player;

    Player.Init();

    cout << Player.exp << " " << Player.level;
    Player.exp += 55;
    cout << " " << Player.exp << " " << Player.level << " ";
}
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"

class Game {
public:
    Game();
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player() {

}

void Player::Init() {
    int exp = 5;
    int level = (exp / 5);
    int attack = (10 + (level * 2));
    int defense = (10 + (level * 2));
    int speed = (10 + (level * 2));
}
```

Player.h:

```
#pragma once
class Player
{
public:
    Player();

    void Init();

    int exp = 5;
    int level = (exp / 5);
    int attack = (10 + (level * 2));
    int defense = (10 + (level * 2));
    int speed = (10 + (level * 2));

};
```

Comment: All those Initialisations shown are nonsensical, unless you use `const` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add 55 to exp, only exp will be changed.

You can write getters and setters and declare the member variables private:

Player.h

```
#pragma once
class Player
{
public:
    Player();

    void Init();

    void addExp(const int additionalExp);
    int getExp();

    //... TODO add similar get/set methods for the other members...

private:
    int exp = 5;
    int level = (exp / 5);
    int attack = (10 + (level * 2));
    int defense = (10 + (level * 2));
    int speed = (10 + (level * 2));
};
```

and add the method definitions:

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player() {

}

void Player::Init() {
    int exp = 5;
    int level = (exp / 5);
    int attack = (10 + (level * 2));
    int defense = (10 + (level * 2));
    int speed = (10 + (level * 2));
}

void Player::addExp(const int additionalExp) {
    if ( additionalExp < 0 ) return; // think about error handling or use 
                                     // unsigned for exp 
    exp += additionalExp;
    level = exp / 50; // or something else, as you like. 
}

int Player::getExp(){ return exp; }

// ... TODO add definitions for the other get/set methods...
```

And use the `addExp()` method in your main.cpp.

One benefit of having the member variables private is that you get more control in how they get manipulated. E.g. if you add `exp`, you can set `level` accordingly simultaneously.